Formatting Column Headers with siunitx
In this table the column headers of the number columns formatted with siunitx seem to be centered. Is there a way to align them to the right, so that the column header itself is right aligned and ends in one line with the percentage sign?

Edit: Extended to Minimum Working Example
The LaTeX code for the table looks like this. I compile it with XeLaTeX.
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}% before geometry!
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.6in, bottom=1in,headheight=23pt,includehead
}
\newcommand*{\useportrait}{%
  \clearpage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,DIV=current}%switch to portrait
  \newgeometry{% geometry settings for portrait
    left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.6in, bottom=1in,headheight=23pt,includehead
  }%
  \fancyhfoffset{0pt}% <- recalculate head and foot width for fancyhdr
}
\newcommand*{\uselandscape}{%
  \clearpage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}%switch to landscape
  \newgeometry{% geometry settings for landscap
    left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.6in, bottom=1in,headheight=23pt,includehead
  }%
  \fancyhfoffset{0pt}% recalculate head and foot width for fancyhdr
}

\sisetup{
    round-mode          = places,
    group-digits        =  true,
    output-decimal-marker = {.},
    group-separator = {,},
    detect-all
}

% Settings
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\geometry{paper=a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize\thepage}

% Caption
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{1pt}

% Page breaks
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\clearpage\oldsection}

% List of figures/tables
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\uselandscape
\section{Global Equities}
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}S[table-format=2.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width=2cm]S[table-format=2.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width=2cm]S[table-format=2.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width=2cm]S[table-format=2.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width=2cm]S[table-format=2.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width=2cm]S[table-format=2.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width=2cm]S[table-format=2.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width=2cm]S[table-format=2.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width=2cm]}
\midrule
{} & {\specialcell{Stock Market \\ Crash \\ 1973-1974}} & {\specialcell{Bear Market \\ 1980-1982}} & {\specialcell{Stock Market \\ Crash \\ 1987}} & {\specialcell{Gulf War \\ 1990}} & {\specialcell{Dot-Com Bubble \\ 2000}} & {\specialcell{Financial \\ Crisis \\ 2008}} & {\specialcell{Equity Markets \\ Rebound \\ 2009}} & {\specialcell{Oil Prices \\ Drop \\ 2010}} \\
\toprule
Nexi SpA & -72.5\si{\percent} & -37.2\si{\percent} & -34.7\si{\percent} & -30.1\si{\percent} & -58.0\si{\percent} & -76.1\si{\percent} & 65.0\si{\percent} & -10.6\si{\percent} \\
Fiserv Inc & -49.9\si{\percent} & 12.8\si{\percent} & -44.1\si{\percent} & -27.5\si{\percent} & -2.6\si{\percent} & -41.5\si{\percent} & 32.6\si{\percent} & -8.2\si{\percent} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


How or where is \specialcell defined?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Which documentclass you use? BTW, our table is 23 cm wide, i.e. more than A4 paper width ... Please extend your code fragment to complete small document.

@cabohah Thank you for pointing this out, I extended it to a minimum example.

Don't specify column widths.
On the other hand, repeating % all over again is boring for the reader.
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize

\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{8}{S[table-format=-2.1\%, round-precision=1]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
  & {\specialcell{Stock Market \\ Crash \\ 1973--1974}}
  & {\specialcell{Bear Market \\ 1980--1982}} 
  & {\specialcell{Stock Market \\ Crash \\ 1987}}
  & {\specialcell{Gulf War \\ 1990}} 
  & {\specialcell{Dot-Com \\ Bubble \\ 2000}}
  & {\specialcell{Financial \\ Crisis \\ 2008}} 
  & {\specialcell{Equity Markets \\ Rebound \\ 2009}}
  & {\specialcell{Oil Prices \\ Drop \\ 2010}} \\
\midrule
Nexi SpA   & -72.5\% & -37.2\% & -34.7\% & -30.1\% & -58.0\% & -76.1\% & 65.0\% & -10.6\% \\
Fiserv Inc & -49.9\% &  12.8\% & -44.1\% & -27.5\% &  -2.6\% & -41.5\% & 32.6\% &  -8.2\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Some caption text}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize

\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{8}{S[table-format=-2.1, round-precision=1]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
  & {\specialcell{Stock Market \\ Crash \\ 1973--1974}}
  & {\specialcell{Bear Market \\ 1980--1982}} 
  & {\specialcell{Stock Market \\ Crash \\ 1987}}
  & {\specialcell{Gulf War \\ 1990}} 
  & {\specialcell{Dot-Com \\ Bubble \\ 2000}}
  & {\specialcell{Financial \\ Crisis \\ 2008}} 
  & {\specialcell{Equity Markets \\ Rebound \\ 2009}}
  & {\specialcell{Oil Prices \\ Drop \\ 2010}} \\
\midrule
Nexi SpA   & -72.5 & -37.2 & -34.7 & -30.1 & -58.0 & -76.1 & 65.0 & -10.6 \\
Fiserv Inc & -49.9 &  12.8 & -44.1 & -27.5 &  -2.6 & -41.5 & 32.6 &  -8.2 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Some caption text, data in percentage}

\end{table}

\end{document}


If you really want right alignment (but I can't see a reason to),
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize

\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{8}{S[table-format=-2.1\%, round-precision=1,table-number-alignment=right]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
  & {\specialcell{Stock Market \\ Crash \\ 1973--1974}}
  & {\specialcell{Bear Market \\ 1980--1982}} 
  & {\specialcell{Stock Market \\ Crash \\ 1987}}
  & {\specialcell{Gulf War \\ 1990}} 
  & {\specialcell{Dot-Com \\ Bubble \\ 2000}}
  & {\specialcell{Financial \\ Crisis \\ 2008}} 
  & {\specialcell{Equity Markets \\ Rebound \\ 2009}}
  & {\specialcell{Oil Prices \\ Drop \\ 2010}} \\
\midrule
Nexi SpA   & -72.5\% & -37.2\% & -34.7\% & -30.1\% & -58.0\% & -76.1\% & 65.0\% & -10.6\% \\
Fiserv Inc & -49.9\% &  12.8\% & -44.1\% & -27.5\% &  -2.6\% & -41.5\% & 32.6\% &  -8.2\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Some caption text}

\end{table}

\end{document}



+1. You may also want to reverse the OP's sequence of \midrule and \toprule directives.

@Mico Didn't notice. I'll fix

Thank you @egreg, is it possible to have the column header text itself right aligned, so that the right aligned text and the percentage sign are aligned along the same right-hand line?

@Hans-PeterSchrei Why would you want that?

It is part of the internal corporate style guideline I have to work with. In case you missed it, I have also extended the example to a minimum working example.

@Hans-PeterSchrei I added it, although my eyes bleed.

you not provide MWE, so we can only guess which document class you use and about page  layout, and how is defined \specialcell command.
žPossible solution can be:

define page layout with use geometry package
for specialcell use thead of malecell
remove definitions of S cells width
instead of tabular use tabular* and determination of distance of columns left to LaTeX:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{S[table-format=-2.1, round-precision=1]} }
    \toprule
    & {\thead{Stock Market \\ Crash \\ 1973-1974}}  & {\thead{Bear\\ Market \\ 1980-1982}} 
    & {\thead{Stock\\ Market \\ Crash \\ 1987}}       & {\thead{Gulf\\ War \\ 1990}}
    & {\thead{Dot-Com\\ Bubble \\ 2000}}              & {\thead{Financial \\ Crisis \\ 2008}}
    & {\thead{Equity Markets \\ Rebound \\ 2009}}   & {\thead{Oil Prices \\ Drop \\ 2010}} \\
    \midrule
    Nexi SpA & -72.5\si{\percent} & -37.2\si{\percent} & -34.7\si{\percent} & -30.1\si{\percent} 
    & -58.0\si{\percent} & -76.1\si{\percent} & 65.0\si{\percent} & -10.6\si{\percent} \\
    Fiserv Inc & -49.9\si{\percent} & 12.8\si{\percent} & -44.1\si{\percent} & -27.5\si{\percent} 
    & -2.6\si{\percent} & -41.5\si{\percent} & 32.6\si{\percent} & -8.2\si{\percent} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


(red lines indicate page layout)
